# Swift facebook SDK cancel share dialog

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, dialog, share

When I click on Cancel or Share button, the dialog always take me to my Facebook page. Is there anayway to make it return to my app when I click on Cancel or Share button. Thanks so much and sorry for my bad English.

This is my Facebook Dialog image
https://www.flickr.com/photos/125253862@N07/16990249387/

This is my Facebook Dialog showing code image
https://www.flickr.com/photos/125253862@N07/16990247507/

This is my code

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import Bolts

class FacebookController: UIViewController {

let UserDef: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults()

func FBsharelink() {

    var playerTime = UserDef.valueForKey("TimeOfPlayer") as! Int
    var playerScore = UserDef.valueForKey("PlayerScore") as! Int

    let content : FBSDKShareLinkContent = FBSDKShareLinkContent()
    content.contentURL = NSURL(string: "https://www.facebook.com/CityDefender")
    content.contentTitle = "I have \(playerScore) scores in \(playerTime) seconds. Come and beat me !"
    content.contentDescription = "City Defender News"

    FBSDKShareDialog.showFromViewController(self, withContent: content, delegate: nil)

}   
}
```

P/s: I cannot post image here :(

Comment: Could you please post your code here, as text and using the code-notation? That way it's easier to analyze and find this question.

Comment: What happens when you click "Share"? Is the user then returned to your app

Comment: @Flaxfield yes I've just added my code above, when i click "Share", it share a post on my timeline then return to my homepage, not my app. I'm using Facebook SDK via Parse.com